# React Router cannot read ToUpperCase of undefined... basic example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have all the correct dependencies installed (react and react-router here) and I am using the most basic example from the React Router Github page... but I cannot get rid of this error.

My React Router is @ 0.13.3 & React is at 0.13.3 as well.

Here's my code, in JSX:

```
import "../css/master.scss";

import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router';

const App = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>App</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="about">About</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
})

const About = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <h3>About</h3>
    }
})

const Contact = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <h3>Contact</h3>
    }
})

const routes = {
  path: '/',
  component: App,
  childRoutes: [
    { path: 'about', component: About },
    { path: 'contact', component: Contact },
  ]
}


React.render(<Router routes={routes} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed up my final statement to match Router.run() and then Rendered my React components. Didn't see this in the quick intro on React-Router.

Sorry StackOverflow V_V

```
import "../css/master.scss";

import React from 'react';
import  Router, { Route, Link } from 'react-router';

const App = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1><Link to="/">App</Link></h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li><Link to="about">About</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="contact">Contact</Link></li>
                    </ul>
                    {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
})

const About = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <h3>About</h3>
    }
})

const Contact = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <h3>Contact</h3>
    }
})

const AppRoutes = (
    <Route path="/" handler={App}>
        <Route name="about" handler={About} />
        <Route name="contact" handler={Contact} />
    </Route>
);


Router.run(AppRoutes, Router.HashLocation, (Root) => {
  React.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```